# Recursive function (Chapman-Kolmogorov eq.) for Transition Probabilities

Tags: python, numpy, recursion

I'm stuck with building a recursive function which is best illustrated through a quick example.

Take a Markov process with 2 states, State 1 and State 2.  The notation *p_ij*  represents the probability of transitioning to state *j* given that the current state is *i*.  In this example,

- p_11 = 0.8 (probability of staying in State 1 given current state is State 1)
- p_12 = 0.2
- p_21 = 0.6
- p_22 = 0.4

And the transition probability matrix is:

```
import numpy as np
pij = np.array([[.8, .2], [.6, .4]])
print(pij)
# [[ 0.8  0.2]
#  [ 0.6  0.4]]
```

The *n*-step transition probability, denoted *r_ij(n)*, represents the probability that the state after *n* time periods will be *j*, given that the current state is *i*.  *r_ij(n)* can be found using the Chapman-Kolmogorov equation,

[image]

with the initial condition

[image]

*m* is the total number of states.  [From Bertsekas/Tsitsiklis, 2008.]

I'm trying to build *r_ij(n)*.  The first 5 steps should look like this:

[image]

**My start**:

```
def r(p, n):
    m = np.sqrt(p.size)  # or p.shape[0]
    if n == 1:
        return p
    elif n > 1:
        res = []
        for k in range(m):
            for i in p:
                for j in i:
                    # This line is patently wrong...
                    # Not sure how to reference i
                    return r(n - 1) * p[k, j]
        return np.sum(res)

p0 = np.array([[.8, .2], [.6, .4]])
print(r(p0, n=5))
# [[.7501, .2499],
#  [.7498, .2502]]
```

But I am a bit lost with the notation.

Comment: You have made a good start. When you defined `pij = np.array([[.8, .2], [.6, .4]])`, a more natural identifier would have been `p`. Similiarly `rij` should be `r`. Your definition says 3 loops: over i, j, k, but you only coded a loop over k. Notice that you're using single subscript where double subscript (like `p[k, j]`) is appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't necessarily need a recursive function for this. `matrix_power` is essentially `rij` you are looking for:

```
def rij(pij, n):
    return matrix_power(pij, n)
```

---

```
pij = np.array([[.8, .2], [.6, .4]])

from numpy.linalg.linalg import matrix_power

matrix_power(pij, 2)
#array([[ 0.76,  0.24],
#       [ 0.72,  0.28]])

matrix_power(pij, 3)
#array([[ 0.752,  0.248],
#       [ 0.744,  0.256]])

matrix_power(pij, 4)
#array([[ 0.7504,  0.2496],
#       [ 0.7488,  0.2512]])

matrix_power(pij, 5)
#array([[ 0.75008,  0.24992],
#       [ 0.74976,  0.25024]])
```

---

To define a recursive function, `np.dot` will make the task easier:

```
def rij(pij, n):
    if n == 1:
        return pij
    else:
        return np.dot(rij(pij, n-1), pij)

rij(pij, 5)
#array([[ 0.75008,  0.24992],
#       [ 0.74976,  0.25024]])
```

Comment: Awesome answer.  Uses `dot` because matrix power is effectively repeated matrix squaring + multiplication?

Comment: Yes. That's essentially what `matrix_power` does, repeated matrix multiplication. Use `np.dot` with recursive function to simulate the process.

Comment: Any way I could vectorize for cases where `n` is a NumPy array?  The `n == 1` test doesn't like that case and `matrix_power` requires `n` as a int.  Result would be 3d, shape (len(n), m, m).

Comment: To add a point to @Psidom 's answer, matrix_power is faster than direct recursive multiplication, because the function uses dynamic programming to reduce the number of multiplications needed.

Comment: I don't think there will be an efficient vectorization for this. If you are calculating this for multiple `n`s, I'd recommend introduce some memoization technique here. For instance with powers `[10, 30, 40]`, you probably don't want to calculate everything from the ground, you want to calcuate `30` based on `10`, `40` based `30` for instance.